# calculate number of frost change days (number of days) from the weather hourly data in r

Tags: r, time, weather

I have to calculate the following data *Number of frost change days***(NFCD)**** as weekly basis.
That means the number of days in which minimum temperature and maximum temperature cross 0°C.
Let's say I work with years 1957-1980 with hourly temp.

Example data (couple of rows look like):

```
Date    Time (UTC)  temperature 
1957-07-01  00:00:00    5
1957-07-01  03:00:00    6.2
1957-07-01  05:00:00    9
1957-07-01  06:00:00    10
1957-07-01  07:00:00    10
1957-07-01  08:00:00    14
1957-07-01  09:00:00    13.2
1957-07-01  10:00:00    15
1957-07-01  11:00:00    15
1957-07-01  12:00:00    16.3
1957-07-01  13:00:00    15.8
```

Expected data:

```
year month  week    NFCD 
1957    7   1        1 
1957    7   2        5
```

Comment: Hi! You can considerably increase your chances of help by providing a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please don't just copy raw text in here.

Comment: An additional note. Your exmaple from above only shows one date for which their is no crossing of the 0°C mark. So it's not a good example. Please share an example that a) has several days and b) also has examples for corssing 0°C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
dat <- data.frame(date=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)), time=rep(1:5, times=2), temp=c(1:5,-2,1:4))
dat
#    date time temp
# 1     A    1    1
# 2     A    2    2
# 3     A    3    3
# 4     A    4    4
# 5     A    5    5
# 6     B    1   -2
# 7     B    2    1
# 8     B    3    2
# 9     B    4    3
# 10    B    5    4
aggregate(temp ~ date, data = dat, FUN = function(z) min(z) <= 0 && max(z) > 0)
#   date  temp
# 1    A FALSE
# 2    B  TRUE
```

(then rename `temp` to `NFCD`)

Comment: Thanks, That means all TRUEs are the NFCD days. Now I want to count NFCD (all TRUEs from your result) per week. You may see my expected NFDC column.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data from r2evans's answer you can also use tidyverse logic:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(NFCD = min(temp) < 0 & max(temp) > 0)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  date  NFCD 
  <chr> <lgl>
1 A     FALSE
2 B     TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, That means all TRUEs are the NFCD days. Now I want to count NFCD (all TRUEs from your result) per week, see my expected NFDC.

Comment: As soon as you'd provide a data example that actually has several weeks covered i'm happy to have a look - see my comment on your post above.

Comment: I ve calculated days and the NFCD whether true or false: 
1957-12-01 TRUE
1957-12-02 TRUE
1957-12-03 TRUE
1957-12-04 TRUE
1957-12-05 FALSE
1957-12-06 FALSE
1957-12-07 FALSE
1957-12-08 FALSE
1957-12-09 FALSE
1957-12-10 FALSE
1957-12-11 FALSE
1957-12-12 FALSE
1957-12-13 FALSE
1957-12-14 FALSE
1957-12-15 FALSE
1957-12-16 TRUE
1957-12-17 FALSE
1957-12-18 TRUE
1957-12-19 FALSE
1957-12-20 FALSE
1957-12-21 FALSE
1957-12-22 FALSE
1957-12-23 FALSE
1957-12-24 FALSE
1957-12-25 FALSE
1957-12-26 FALSE
1957-12-27 FALSE
1957-12-28 FALSE

Comment: Can you please invest a few minutes to read the information shared in the link I posted under your question? I.e. how to provide a data example and all. The pure text you just posted above is not very helpful. Also, please rather update your initial question. Don't post code/results as comments.